# how to make sure email sent

Tags: iphone

I used MFMailComposeViewController to send email.
It always add the email to email queue.
If my email has large attached file, it will take a long time to send out.
Is there a way to make sure email has been sent?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no, there is no way to make sure the email has actually been sent.

The best you can do is in `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` in your `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` check the result is equal to `MFMailComposeResultSent`, and this will tell you the email is queued to be sent.